# Sequelize PostgreSQL index creation error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a table called Post in PostgreSQL using Sequelize. I have the following code to generate the table:

```
const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
  community: Sequelize.STRING,
  block: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  fullPermlink: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  featured: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  featurer: Sequelize.STRING,
  pinned: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
},{
  indexes:[
    {
      unique: false,
      fields:['block']
    }
  ]
});
```

Running this, the DB correctly creates the index for the block column but for some reason also tries to create `indexes` as a row itself. Here's the logs it gives with logging enabled:

```
Executing (default): CREATE INDEX "posts_block" ON "posts" ("block")
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "pinnedposts" ("id"   SERIAL , "community" VARCHAR(255), "fullPermlink" VARCHAR(255), "indexes" [object Object], "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "["
```

This seems like a really weird error to me, thanks for the help ahead of time!

Comment: Do you have `sequelize.define` for `pinnedpost`?  It looks index is correctly created for `posts`.

Comment: I think I see what happened now @Emma, I define pinnedpost after posts.